# Gulp Dependent Tasks

Tags: javascript, node.js, build, gulp, concatenation

In order to build the final JS source for a web app, I am compiling JavaScript templates, CoffeScript sources and vanilla JS vendor scripts. A final task, dependent on the former three, would then concatenate the scripts together into one file.

The following setup, in which I define the last task with dependencies to the first three, the final step never executes. It seems that process doesn't wait until the partial files are written to the disc.

I tried merging event streams as well, but it seems to be an overkill for something like this. I'd appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction here.

```
// compile JS templates
gulp.task('js-build-template', function() {
    gulp.src('./../app/assets/javascripts/**/*.jst.eco')
        .pipe(eco({ basePath: 'app/assets/javascripts', namespace: 'JST_ATL' }))
        .pipe(concat('_templates.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/assets/scripts/partials'));
});

// compile CoffeeScript source
gulp.task('js-build-source', function() {
    gulp.src(js.source)
        .pipe(coffee())
        .pipe(concat('_source.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/assets/scripts/partials'));
});

// compile vendor scripts
gulp.task('js-build-vendor', function() {
    gulp.src(js.vendor)
        .pipe(concat('_vendor.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/assets/scripts/partials'));
});

// concatenate and fingerprint files
gulp.task('js-build', [ 'js-build-template', 'js-build-source', 'js-build-vendor' ], function() {
    gulp.src([ 'public/assets/scripts/partials/_templates.js', 'public/assets/scripts/partials/_vendor.js', 'public/assets/scripts/partials/_source.js' ])
        .pipe(concat('app.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/assets/scripts'))
        .pipe(rev())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/assets/scripts'))
        .pipe(rev.manifest())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/assets/scripts'));
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in all 3 of your task you need return statements

```
gulp.task('js-build-template', function() {
    return gulp.src('./../app/assets/javascripts/**/*.jst.eco')
        .pipe(eco({ basePath: 'app/assets/javascripts', namespace: 'JST_ATL' }))
        .pipe(concat('_templates.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/assets/scripts/partials'));
});
```

this will help in letting final task know that they have finished and it needs to start...